# SQL Lag() in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

I was wondering if there is a way to get the functionality of [SQL LAG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in my SPARQL query. More specifically, I have a set of states like

```
<http:\\stateA> p:start "2014-05-23T10:20:13+05:30"^^xsd:dateTime
<http:\\stateB> p:start "2014-06-23T10:20:13+05:30"^^xsd:dateTime
<http:\\stateC> p:start "2014-07-23T10:20:13+05:30"^^xsd:dateTime
```

And I want to find the duration of each state. The duration of each state, lets say state A, can be computed by subtracting the start of the next state (here it is state B) from the start of state A. So I need a way to find the next state with respect to each state.

Comment: `select ?x ?d {
?x p:start ?s1 .
?y p:start ?s2 .
FILTER(?s2 > ?s1)
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?z p:start ?s3 FILTER(?s3 > ?s1 && ?s3 < ?s2)}
BIND(?s2 - ?s1 AS ?d)
}`

Answer (score 0):

These functions aren't yet part of SPARQL, but [SEP-002](https://github.com/w3c/sparql-12/blob/main/SEP/SEP-0002/sep-0002.md) for [proposed SPARQL 1.2 updates](https://www.w3.org/community/sparql-12/) includes more XSD functions, including [`xsd:dateTime - xsd:dateTime`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-subtract-dateTimes). This is likely implemented in many implementations by now, although possibly with some setup required.

I've implemented it in my [Ruby implementation](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/sparql#sparql-12).